# "Nothing but seventh place is good enough"

Tags: idiom, sentence-translation

I would like help modifying the famous phrase *nil satis nisi optimum* to lower expectations somewhat to "nothing but seventh place is good enough". Google Translate creates a suspicious range of different suggestions, so I thought I'd ask the experts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To parallel *optimum* ("best", singular neuter nominative), I would go with *septimum* ("seventh", same form).
Therefore I suggest ***nil satis nisi septimum***.
Funnily enough, it sounds very similar to the original, which is always a good bonus for an analogy.

As brianpck comments below, *optimum* means "the best [thing]".
Similarly, my *septimum* means "the seventh [thing]", not so much "the seventh place".
But I think the message is clear enough in this form, and the word play would be diluted by additional words.

Comment: Hmm...my reservation is that *optimum* means "the best [thing]" whereas *septimum* doesn't lend itself to that kind of abstraction. Do you know of any examples where ordinal numbers stand for "X place"?